# issue with different methods to loop over a std::vector and getting pointer to its elements

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

let me preface by saying that i'm not a c++ expert here, so i apologize in advance if what i'm trying to figure out is trivial for most. i have tried to find the solution to this in other posts, but this time i haven't succeeded.

at the end of the post you can find the standalone code that reproduces the 2 issues i'm about to detail [*].

i'm using a class `A` containing a `std::vector<float>` as member, which can be accessed via a const method.

- issue #1: after the vector is filled, i try to print out its content with a loop, in two different ways.

loop #1

```
  for(const auto& af : a.vec()){

    std::cout << af << " (address=" << &af << ")\n";
  }
```

loop #2

```
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<a.vec().size(); ++i){

    const auto& af = a.vec().at(i);
    std::cout << af << " (address=" << &af << ")\n";
  }
```

the 2 approaches seem to yield 2 different results. loop #1 works as expected. when using loop #2, i get that the value of some of the vector elements is now (printed out as) zero, but the memory addresses are still the right ones.
naively, i expected the two approaches to give the same output. what is the reason why they differ?

- issue #2: given the above vector of floats `vec` and a value `a` chosen by the user, i'm trying to get a pointer to the element of `vec` whose value is closer to `a`. in the code example below, there is a routine that tries to accomplish that. the latter routine actually returns the correct pointer (which i save as a `const float*` object), but then, when dereferencing, the value printed out is zero (similarly to what happens in loop#2 of issue#1). i don't understand why this happens because the original vector still exists, the memory-address is correct and non-null, but when dereferencing the value is zero, which is different from the value of the vector element pointed to.

below i wrote down some instructions to reproduce these two issues.

any insight on the reason why these 2 issues arise (and/or general suggestions on the implementation below) is welcome.

thanks

[*] i'm compiling the code below (`test.cc`) with g++ version 4.9.1 in SLC6, doing `g++ test.cc -o test -std=c++0x`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

class A {
 public:
  explicit A() {}
  virtual ~A() {}

  std::vector<float> a_vec() const { return a_vec_; }

  void add_obj(const float f){

    a_vec_.push_back(f);

    return;
  }

 private:
  std::vector<float> a_vec_;
};

template<typename T>
const T * closest0(const float& f, const std::vector<T>& fvec){

  const T* next=0;

  float deltarmin = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<fvec.size(); ++i) {
    const T & fi = fvec[i];
    const float dr = fabs(fi-f);
    if(dr < deltarmin){

      deltarmin = dr;
      next = &fi;
    }
  }

  return next;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  if(argc-1 != 1) return 0;

  const float ref(atoi(argv[1]));
  ////

  A a;
  a.add_obj(25.);
  a.add_obj(35.);
  a.add_obj(45.);
  a.add_obj(55.);

  std::cout << "\n*** input vector ***********\n";
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<a.a_vec().size(); ++i){
    std::cout << "a.a_vec().at(" << i << ")=" << a.a_vec().at(i) << " (address=" << &a.a_vec().at(i) << ")\n";
  }
  std::cout <<   "****************************\n";

  int tryN(0);
  ////

  ++tryN;
  std::cout << "\n--- loop:(const auto&)" << std::endl;
  for(const auto& af : a.a_vec()){

    std::cout << "#" << tryN << " " << af << " (address=" << &af << ")\n";
  }
  std::cout << "---------------" << std::endl;
  ////

  ++tryN;
  std::cout << "\n--- loop:(index) + 'const auto& ... at()'\n";
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<a.a_vec().size(); ++i){

    const auto& af = a.a_vec().at(i);
    std::cout << "#" << tryN << " " << af << " (address=" << &af << ")\n";
  }
  std::cout << "---------------" << std::endl;
  ////

  std::cout << "\n---------------\n\n";

  const float* fclo0 = closest0(ref, a.a_vec());
  std::cout << " *** f-closest0(" << ref << ")=" << *fclo0 << " (address=" << fclo0 << ")\n";

  return 0;
}
```

an example of the output i'm getting is

```
$ ./test 33


*** input vector ***********

a.a_vec().at(0)=25 (address=0x1a4f030)

a.a_vec().at(1)=35 (address=0x1a4f034)

a.a_vec().at(2)=45 (address=0x1a4f038)

a.a_vec().at(3)=55 (address=0x1a4f03c)

****************************



--- loop:(const auto&)

#1 25 (address=0x1a4f030)

#1 35 (address=0x1a4f034)

#1 45 (address=0x1a4f038)

#1 55 (address=0x1a4f03c)

---------------


--- loop:(index) + 'const auto& ... at()'

#2 6.05888e-38 (address=0x1a4f030)

#2 0 (address=0x1a4f034)

#2 45 (address=0x1a4f038)

#2 55 (address=0x1a4f03c)

---------------


---------------


 *** f-closest0(33)=0 (address=0x1a4f034)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@juanchopanza correctly points out that `a_vec()` is returning by value, but that doesn't explain the output completely. The issue is that

```
 const auto& af = a.a_vec().at(i);
 std::cout << "#" << tryN << " " << af << " (address=" << &af << ")\n";
```

The first line binds a reference to a value that was returned from a temporary copy of the data, which then goes out of scope, so by the time you access `af` again, the underlying memory has been reclaimed and may have been overwritten.

The reason the const reference doesn't extend the lifetime of the temporary is that it is a reference to a result of using the temporary in the expression, not a reference to the temporary itself. If you instead did

```
  const auto &vec = a.a_vec();
  std::cout << "#" << tryN << " " << vec.at(i) << " (address=" << &vec.at(i) << ")\n";
```

then it should be OK. (Though the right answer is to have `a_vec` return a const ref to the vector in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

`A::a_vec()` returns by value. You get a new vector each time you call it. You could fix this by returning a reference

```
const std::vector<float>& a_vec() const { return a_vec_; }
```

or making `a_vec_` public and accessing it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second loop

`for(unsigned int i=0; i<a.a_vec().size(); ++i){
     const auto& af = a.a_vec().at(i);
     std::cout << "#" << tryN << " " << af << " (address=" << &af << ")\n";
 }`

It's because of the declaration of the variable, `const auto&`. If you were to remove the ampersand and hold it by value instead of by reference, it works, so just declare it as `const auto`

Answer (score 0):

I think this statement is suspect:

```
const auto& af = a.a_vec().at(i);
```

I believe the std::vector returned by a.a_vec() goes out of scope after the statement ends.  Yet you still have a reference to one of it's members.

You can fix this by taking a reference to the **entire vector** like this:

```
const auto & av = a.a_vec();
```

Or copying an **element** like this:

```
const auto af = a.a_vec().at(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<a.a_vec().size(); ++i){

    const &auto af = a.a_vec().at(i);
    std::cout << "#" << tryN << " " << af << " (address=" << &af << ")\n";
}
```

for #2, Remove the & before auto and it will work the same.  Your getting a Value not a reference in the second loop!

```
const auto af = a.a_vec().at(i);
```